# Mysql Join Issue

Tags: mysql

Hi i need help with a query.

I have 4 tables

articles - id, category_id, user_id
categories - id
article_category - article_id, category_id
users - id

The category_id in the article table is used determine the main category

Now I want to get all articles so i uses the query below.

Article can have more than one category. I want to see a list of articles with the main category information attached

SELECT a.*, c.title , c.slug
FROM articles a, article_category ac, categories c, users u
WHERE **ac.article_id = a.category_id** is supposed to be **ac.article_id = a.id** 
AND ac.category_id = c.id
AND a.user_id = u.id
AND ac.category_id = '1'

Problem with this query is that i get the incorrect category information and i dont think i should run a subquery like the one below to solve it

(select title from categories where id = a.category_id) as title

Thanks

Comment: WHERE ac.article_id = a.category_id, should be WHERE ac.category_id = a.category_id

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting the "main" category information for all the articles? Can your articles have more than one category? Are you wanting to see each article once or repeated for each category attached to it?

Comment: @cfreak article can have more than one category. I want to see all article once with the main category information attached

Answer (score 0):

Your join clauses were incorrect. I have re-written it in ANSI syntax to make it more readable, and the `JOIN` clauses more explicit:

```
SELECT a.*, c.title , c.slug
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN article_category ac on ac.category_id = a.category_id
INNER JOIN categories c on ac.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN users u on a.user_id = u.id
WHERE ac.category_id = '1'
```

Incidentally, you are JOINing against the `users` table but not selecting any columns from it, so you can remove that join unless you are using it to filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

Removed users table from query (does not used at all), changed condition from ac.article_id = a.category_id to ac.category_id = a.category_id

```
      SELECT a.*, c.title , c.slug 
      FROM articles a, article_category ac, categories c
      WHERE ac.category_id = a.category_id
      AND ac.category_id = c.id
      AND ac.category_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, c.title, c.slug
from articles a
join article_category ac on a.id = ac.article_id
join categories c on ac.category_id = c.id
join users u on a.user_id = u.id
where c.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you're joining on article_id=category_id, that doesn't make sense, try that instead:

```
SELECT a.*, c.title , c.slug FROM articles a, article_category ac, categories c, users u
WHERE ac.category_id = a.category_id
AND ac.category_id = c.id
AND a.user_id = u.id
AND ac.category_id = '1'
```